# Is there any way how i can use int variable to complete component name?

Tags: c++, c++builder

Can I use for example int variable x=5 to get to the component number 5, Image1,Image2...Image5.

Like you use variable in arrays to select specific element of array array[x].

Comment: No. Use an array.

Comment: The question is unclear to me, because the obvious solution for what you want to achieve is using arrays, but you already seem to be aware of them. You will have to give more details, examples and try for more clarity to make this question answerable. `array[x]` is even the precise syntax for doing what you seem to ask about. Please explain what is unclear about how to do it and/or what is blocking you.

Comment: Yes, you can do exactly what you did. The only thing you can't do is specify the array length with a variable.

Comment: Okay, i am working in C++ Builder, i have one button which should load image to one of 5 image components in form, it depents on integer variable which Image component is going to be used, im not sure if there is any way for me to use that integer variable to "select" image component, if my variable is 4 i should use Image4 to load my image.
Im sorry if i am unclear, im still learning. Thank you for advice.

Comment: Create an array of these buttons (or pointers to them) and use the variable to access that array.

Answer (score 1):

Not *directly*, no.  Meaning, something like this will not work:

```cpp
int x = 5;
Imagex->...
```

Or:

```cpp
int x = 5;
(Image + x)->...
```

As other answers have stated, you can instead store the component pointers into an array, and then use the variable to index into that array as needed, eg:

```cpp
TImage* Images[5];
...
Images[0] = Image1;
Images[1] = Image2;
Images[2] = Image3;
Images[3] = Image4;
Images[4] = Image5;
...
int x = 5;
Images[x-1]->...
```

There is another option - you can use the component owner's `FindComponent()` method (where the `TForm` is the `Owner` for any components placed at design-time), eg:

```cpp
int x = 5;
static_cast<TImage*>(Owner->FindComponent("Image"+String(x)))->...
```

Which you can then couple with the array approach, by using `FindComponent()` in a loop to avoid hard-coding the references:

```cpp
TImage* Images[5];
...
for(int num = 1; i <= 5; ++num)
    Images[num-1] = static_cast<TImage*>(Owner->FindComponent("Image"+String(num)));
...
int x = 5;
Images[x-1]->...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use vector holding, lets say images and then use carefully your custom function to get the image by index, the trick you need to be aware of is that if somehow the vector is sorted or any element changes its position, then you code is going to be broken...

here an example..

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<abc::file> files {file1,file2,file3,file4};
abc::file getByIndex(int index)
{
    if(index<0 || index>files.size())
        return abc::file::invalid;
    return files.at(index);
}

int main()
{
    int i = 5; 
    abc::file5 = getByIndex(i);
    std::cout << 'here is the end\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way how i can use int variable to complete component name?

No.

However, there is also no need to because:

> you use variable in arrays to select specific element of array array[x].

In conclusion: You can use an array instead.